# App crashed with "Fail to find supported surface info - CameraId:null" CameraX

Tags: android, crash, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using new CameraX API (alpha 5).

On devices like: LGE, Samsung, Motorola, OPPO crash with message:

```
Fail to find supported surface info - CameraId:null
```

occur.

This crashes are rare, but unacceptable.

Error occur in method:

```
     private fun initCamera(cameraMode: CameraMode) {
        val lensFacing = if (cameraMode == CameraMode.DEFAULT) CameraX.LensFacing.BACK else CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { textureView?.display?.getRealMetrics(it) }
        val resolution = Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(resolution)
                .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
                .build()

        preview?.let { CameraX.unbind(preview) }
        preview = Preview(previewConfig)
        preview?.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
            val parent = textureView?.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.removeView(textureView)
            parent.addView(textureView, 0)
            textureView?.surfaceTexture = previewOutput.surfaceTexture
        }

        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview)
    }
```

in line:

```
preview = Preview(previewConfig)
```

It is looks like that it cannot create preview for this devices because cannot get camera.

Is anyone know the possible workaround for this problem?

P.S:
I checked. This devices (device models in which crash occur) has both cameras (front, back).

Comment: Can you specify some details about the devices in which this "rare" crash occurs ? Like OS version or device model. Mostly some particular Vendors have different implementations of Camera API so it's quite possible some range of devices may produce unexcepted results.

Comment: Models in which crash occur is: LG K10 LTE, LG K10 (2017), LG X Style, Galaxy J6+, Galaxy J8,  Galaxy Grand Prime, Moto G (2nd Gen), Oppo CPH1903. About versions: I doesn't see any correlation in Android version.

Comment: If this issue is rare, I would suggest you add some Milli Seconds delay before initializing.

Comment: How can it help? :)

Comment: Its just a hitch that maybe sometimes it takes some time to initialize, and tthe value is still null.

Comment: @SharpEdge
Device
Brand: OPPO
Model: A37f
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 525.55 MB
Disk free: 2.66 GB
Operating System
Version: 5.1.1
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted: No
Crash
Date: Jan 20, 2020, 11:39:00 AM
App version: 2.13.0 (280)

Comment: @PeterStaranchuk any solution does delay helped?